# Need help writing .htaccess / Apache rule

Tags: htaccess, apache

I have some URLs which are now 404 due to site upgrade.

I want all URLs starting with `www.example.com/archives/*` to point to `www.example.com/news` (notice that after archives there is a wildcard char).

Can someone here please help me with the code for *.htaccess* rules?

Comment: I've updated my answer pl. see it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to redirect permanently:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/archives/.*  http://www.example.com/news
```

I've placed this rule in `www.tariffplansindia.com` test it there.

Here is another:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/archives [NC]
RewriteRule ^archives/(.*) http://example.com/news [R=301,L]
```

I've placed this rule in `www.rtidiary.org` test it there.

Comment: Hi would the term "RedirectMatch" work in htaccess? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi tried adding the line above to .htaccess and it didn't work! Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Hi I tried looking for any mention of "alias" in the .htaccess file and there is none! Can you please give me the complete code? Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work I added the line above into .htaccess and tried an old url that has the archives in the beginning of the url and it didn't load gave 404.

Comment: It adds url to the new url:

Comment: Hi it doesn't work. It adds the old url to the new url example.com/news/whateverafterarchiveurl

Answer (score 0):

To learn about *.htaccess* writing rules you can refer the official link of 
Apache Module `mod_rewrite`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

And for URL rewriting guide: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html.